# React Functional Component - Store some prop calculation in const vs state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-functional-component

I have a component which renders only once and then is being destroyed,
I've implemented the "Comp3" way.

Using "useEffect" to calculate the str with the num value I received as a prop, then stored the result using "useEffect" setter in order to use the result in the html.

```
//Let say this function is inside the functional component
function numToStr(num:number):string{
  switch(num){
    case 1:
      return "One";
    case 2:
      return "Two";
    ...
  }
}
```

```
function Comp1({num:number}){
  const numAsStr = numToStr(num);
  return <span>{numAsStr}</span>
}
```

```
function Comp2({num:number}){
  const [numAsStr] = useState(numToStr(num));
  return <span>{numAsStr}</span>
}
```

```
function Comp3({num:number}){
  const [numAsStr,setNumAsStr] = useState();
  useEffect(()=>{
    setNumAsStr(numToStr(num));
  },[])
  return <span>{numAsStr}</span>
}
```

```
function Comp4({num:number}){
  const numAsStr = useMemo(()=>numToStr(num),[]);
  return <span>{numAsStr}</span>
}
```

My question is:

What is the best solution in terms of **best-practice/ "react-way"**?

How each implementation effect the **performance**?

Does the fact that I know the component only renders once should impact way I choose to implement?

Or should I treat this component as if i don't know it should be render once and in this case still support the option to "watch" over the prop being changed? (add it to the useEffect / useMemo arrays)

Thanks!

Comment: Why overcomplicate things, `const Comp1 = ({ num }) => <span>{numToStr(num)}</span>;`.

Comment: There's no advantage of storing it in state, and definitely not setting that state in an effect. State is for values that change over time. This does not fit that description.

Comment: My calculation function is different than the one i showcased here.. so its not "overcomplicating" im trying to understand the best practice + performance issues i might be dealing with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the calculations being done by `strToNum` are cheap (as they are in your simplified example), then the approach in `Comp1` is probably the best and simplest. They'll run each time the component re-renders, so they're always up-to-date.

If the calculations are expensive, the recommended way to deal with this is [the `useMemo` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), like in your `Comp4` example. However, you'd want to make sure to include `num` input variable in your dependents array so that `numAsStr` gets re-computed whenever `num` changes. E.g:

```
function Comp4({num:number}){
  const numAsStr = useMemo(()=>numToStr(num),[num]);
  return <span>{numAsStr}</span>
}
```

Using `useState` as you have in `Comp2` would only run `numToStr` in the initial render, so you'd get stale values if `num` ever changed.

Using `useEffect` as you have in `Comp3` introduces an unnecessary double-render - e.g. it renders first without a value for `numAsStr` and then renders again.

I know you said that you are currently sure that it never re-renders again - so some of the downsides/gotchas mentioned above might not apply in this case (and then I'd just go with the `Comp1` approach, because it's simpler) but in my experience, it's best not to make that assumption - will you (or a team-mate) remember that in a month when you try to refactor something?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explenation! Is there a best-practice / react-way for these kind of components? Or every case got should be treated different?

Comment: Glad I could help! If you're satisfied that my answer solved your problem, would you mind hitting the checkbox next to the answer to mark it as "accepted"? That helps others know that you considered the answer the right one, and it's a nice way of saying "thank you" :-)

Comment: Re: is there a "best-practice" - my rule of thumb is to keep things simple (e.g. `Comp1`) as a baseline, reach for `useMemo` to optimize expensive calculations, reach for `useEffect` to do asynchronous stuff (e.g. data fetching), and reach for `useState` only for things that truly are state (e.g. they can't be derived from anything else).

Comment: Here's a great article that goes into more depth: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-sync-state-derive-it

Comment: After processing the answer and reviewing my code once again i came up with a related question..
instead of using useState, i can just declare a let variable in the component and reassign it using "useEffect" every time i want to.
Why would i ever use "useState" hook?

Comment: Re-assigning a simple `let` variable used in a component won't inform react that it needs to re-render with the new values. That's the purpose of the `setMyState` function returned by `const [myState, setMyState] = useState()`.

Comment: If there is a prop in the useEffect deps array, the component will re-render anyway because of the change in the props.. am i wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238618/discussion-between-andrew-stegmaier-and-eden-katabi).